# Realm is saving only my most recently added object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to save my array of objects in Realm, but Realm appears to be saving only the last object.

This is my model class:

```
class ContactEntry: Entry {
    dynamic var contactId: Int = 0
    dynamic var email: String? = ""
    dynamic var phone: String? = ""
    dynamic var building: String? = ""
    dynamic var room: String? = ""
    dynamic var contactDescription: String? = ""
    dynamic var worktime: String? = ""
    dynamic var address: String? = ""
    dynamic var personEntries: PersonEntry?
}
```

This is the base class:

```
class Entry: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? { return "id" }
}
```

This is code I'm using for saving:

```
func createOrUpdate(entities: [Entity]) {
    let entries = toEntries(entities)
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(entries, update: true)
    }
}

func toEntry(entity: Contact) -> ContactEntry {
    let entry = ContactEntry()
    entry.contactId = entity.id
    entry.email = entity.email
    entry.phone = entity.phone
    entry.building = entity.building
    entry.room = entity.room
    entry.contactDescription = entity.description
    entry.worktime = entity.worktime
    entry.address = entity.address
    entry.personEntries = personDAO.toEntry(entity.person)
    return entry
}

func toEntry(entity: Person) -> PersonEntry {
    let entry = PersonEntry()
    entry.personId = entity.id
    entry.firstname = entity.firstname
    entry.middlename = entity.middlename
    entry.lastname = entity.lastname
    entry.photo = entity.photo
    return entry
}
```

I think that it may be because I have relationship in my model, but I'm not sure why they'd be a problem.
I'm using them as described in the Realm documentation.

Comment: Where's the code in which you add multiple items? Can't see any Array there

Comment: maybe the id is same so it become one...

Comment: @LucaNicoletti You can see multiple items in "func createOrUpdate(entities: [Entity])"

Comment: @Tj3n So, you're right! Thank you!

Comment: toEntries function is not presented at all.